# Program is not calculating functions after user enters string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, pointers

I have run into an issue with my program. The program here is supposed to accept a pointer to a C-string as an argument and calculate the number of words contained in the string as well as the number of letters in the string. Both of those values are supposed to be communicated back to the main function, but without using global variables. After that function, I am supposed to write another function that accepts the number of letters and the number of words and sends the average number of letters per word (or average word size) back to the main function. The functions I wrote are supposed to do all of the above and also exclude punctuation and spaces from the counts. The problem I am having though is that when I enter string as the user and press enter, no calculations occur. I can keep pressing enter until no end, and I cannot figure out why that is happening. Any insight would be appreciated, I am new to pointers and C-String.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void Count_All(char*, int&, double&, int&); // Function prototype.
double Calc_Average (char*, int, int, double); // Function prototype.

int main()
{
    const int size = 500;
    char userString[size];
    int Word = 0;
    int Pun = 0;
    double Total_Characters = 0;
    double Average = 0.0;

    cout << "Please enter a string of 500 or less characters: ";
    cin.getline(userString, size);
    cout << "\n";

    Count_All (userString, Word, Total_Characters, Pun);
    cout << "Number of words in the string: " << Word << "\n";
    Average = Calc_Average (userString, Word, Pun, Total_Characters);
    cout <<"\nAverage number of letters per word: "<< fixed <<
    showpoint << setprecision(2) << Average << "\n" << endl;


    cin.ignore(1);
    return 0;
}

void Count_All (char*strptr, int &Word, double &Total_Characters, int &Pun) // Counts all characters and types.
{
    int index = 0;

    while (*strptr != '\0')
    {
        if ((isspace(*strptr)) || (ispunct(*strptr)))
        {
            while ((isspace(*strptr)) || (ispunct(*strptr)))
            {
                index++;
            }
        }

        if ((isalnum(*strptr)) || (ispunct(*strptr)))
        {
            Word++;
            while ((isalnum(*strptr))||(ispunct(*strptr)))
            {
                index++;
                Total_Characters++; // Counting the total printable characters (including digits and punctuation).

                if((ispunct(*strptr)))
                {
                    Pun++; // Counting punctuation.
                }

            }
        }
        index++;
    }
}

double Calc_Average(char*strptr, int Word, int Pun, double Total_Characters)  // Calculates the average number of characters per words.
{
    double Average = 0.0;
    Total_Characters = Total_Characters - Pun; // Subtracting punctuation from all of the characters in the string (not including spaces).
    Average = (Total_Characters / Word);
    return Average;
}
```

Comment: After you enter a string nothing is printed, you press enter and it just keeps starting new lines.

Answer (score 0):

You have double infinite loop in `Count_All` function implementation.

I've fixed your two functions and simplified them. It was difficult for me without huge changes. And why `total` has type `double`? How characters number can be non-integer?

```
void Count_All(const char* strptr, int& word, int& total, int& pun)
{
    bool last_isalnum = false;
    for (word = total = pun = 0; *strptr != '\0'; ++strptr) {
        bool cur_isalnum = isalnum(*strptr) != 0;
        bool cur_ispunct = ispunct(*strptr) != 0;
        if (last_isalnum != cur_isalnum)
            ++word;
        if (cur_ispunct)
            ++pun;
        if (cur_ispunct || cur_isalnum)
            ++total;
        last_isalnum = cur_isalnum;
    }
}

double Calc_Average(int word, int pun, int total)
{
    return static_cast<double>(total - pun) / word;
}
```

Comment: should I just put a break above the last bracket?

Comment: @Zjm4192 a `strptr++` and a test for the end of the string should be sufficient.

Comment: What do the "cur" and last" words do?

Comment: @Zjm4192 `cur_` is for currently processing symbol. `last_` is for symbol that was processed before current. P. S. I could be not good at English.

Answer (score 0):

You never advance `strptr`, so all of your comparisons are against the same `char` and `Count_All` loops forever.

You should replace all instances of `index++` with `strptr++`.  That will cause `strptr` to move down the string and look at each character, instead of looking at the same character over and over again.  After doing this `index` is unused, and can be removed.

Additionally, your final `strptr++` should be inside the `if` block above it to avoid accidentally stepping past the end of your string and into the unknown.

Better yet would be to use a `std::string` and get rid of all these sorts of issues that arise from using raw `char[]`s.

Comment: Including replacing

int index = 0

or does that stay the same?

Comment: Updated.  You never actually use `index`, so you don't need it at all.

Comment: okay so I can delete the "int index = 0" and then go through and replace all of the "index++" with strptr++?

Comment: @Zjm4192 if allowed by the constraints of your assignment, seriously consider Miles' recommendation of using `std::string`.

Comment: @user4581301 I think the first `while` condition is sufficient check for the end of string.  A check for `nullptr` would be good, but isn't the problem here so I didn't mention it.  `std::string` would, of course, alleviate the need for either of those checks.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use std::string as I have not learned about it yet.

Comment: @Zjm4192 no time like the present to learn. If you always wait to be taught, you will have a very hard time holding a job.

Comment: @user4581301 In that case `strptr` ends up pointing to the NUL terminator.  The final `strptr++` should be inside the last `if` block to guard against stepping past the terminator and into the unknown.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, it seems like you have infinite loops here

```
while ((isspace(*strptr)) || (ispunct(*strptr))) (line 42)
```

and here

```
while ((isalnum(*strptr)) || (ispunct(*strptr)))   (line 51)
```

You are always checking the content of the same location without doing any pointer arithmetic to advance the memory location you are checking.